# Cannot Install MongoDB on AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install MongoDB on my AWS EC2 instance.

I try to follow the tutorial https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/ and created the first step by creating the repo file.

Now I am trying to run the command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

I get this error:
[![Picture of error][1]][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNiOQ.png

Openssl is successfully installed but there are no libcrypto.so.10 and libssl.so.10, instead they are only named libcrypto.so and libssl.so. I found nothing on how to change the version and even chatgpt could not help me.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Regarding the missing files, you can create a symbolic links, e.g. `ln -s libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.10`